# SQL Availability Group Validation Error

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I am trying to add a replica in a different subnet to my availability group and keep running into an error. I have confirmed the default file locations are the same on both servers but can't figure out why I am getting this error.[image]

Answer (score 6):

This isn't saying the default file locations need to be the same, this is saying that you don't have identical paths for all files in the database(s) on the secondary server.

Example:

```
Primary Replica: Database files are in E:\Mount1\, E:\Mount2\, F:\Mount3

Secondary Replica: Existing directories E:\Mount1\, F:\Mount3
```

You'll notice that the secondary replica is missing `E:\Mount2\`

The fix is to make the secondary have identical paths for the databases involved.

Comment: You are awesome. out of all 9 of my DB's one was placed in a different folder and one subfolder was missing. I added it and that solved my problem. Thanks for your help.